# How can I make a Menu Block not auto-expand the current page's menu links?

Tags: routes, blocks

I want my menu block to decide whether to show link children based *only* on whether the menu link (or the entire menu block) is set to "Expanded", *not* whether you're currently on the same page as the link that has children. What's the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently doing this with `hook_menu_block_alter()` *calling itself recursively:*

```
function THEME_NAME_menu_block_tree_alter(&$tree, &$config) {
    if($config['expanded']) {
        return;
    }

    foreach($tree as $link_key => &$link) {
        if(!empty($link['below'])) {
            if(!$link['link']['expanded']) {
                $link['below'] = array();
            } else {
                THEME_NAME_menu_block_tree_alter($link['below'], $config);
            }
        }
    }

    unset($link);
}
```

But this feels super sketchy and I'm not at all confident that it's the best solution. I could break the `foreach()` into a separate recursive function, but that hardly seems different, other than my general icky feeling which I'm not sure there's even a logical reason for me to have.